# post in private channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to write a telegram python bot that posts in my private channel for Authorized users only

I succeeded to make a bot that work only for Authorized users but i cant finish that and cant find anything that can help, need to know how can i make that Authorized user can save post in memory and press in the botton Whenever he wants to post in the channel

stuck from here ;

```
@restricted
def start(update, context):
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("change post", callback_data='1'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("show saved post", callback_data='2')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("post in channel", callback_data='3')]]
```

anyone can help me please? **Thanks in advance**

Comment: what's and where is the problem exactly ?

Comment: @mujad Don't know how to proceed the code

Comment: I suggest read this examples before everything these are the best practice codes of python-telegram-bot and will help you, https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples .